# Автоматическое обновление страницы в Сhrome после сохранения(изменения) определенного файла.

Tags: google-chrome, вёрстка, браузер

Можно настроить чтобы не обновлять страницу, а при сохранении определенного файла браузер обновлятся сам???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую расширение Emmet LiveStyle для Chrome в паре с редактором Sublime text. Изменяя значения в css-файле, я могу сразу видеть их в окне браузера, не обновляя его и даже не сохраняя эти изменения в редакторе.

Comment: Это просто идеальная штука!!!

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться browsersync - универсальное решение для любой IDE http://nikovit.ru/blog/browsersync-poleznyy-instrument-dlya-verstalshchika/

Если вы используете PhpStorm то для него есть плагин Live Edit http://nikovit.ru/blog/live-edit-dlya-phpstorm-poleznyy-instrument-verstalshchika-/